# Get operation (without Option) in Backbone using beforeSend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, backbone.js, get

Based on answers of the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474139/how-to-specify-url-and-header-in-backbone-to-use-crud-method-on-my-model) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081728/add-request-header-on-backbone) questions, i wrote the following code to GET:

```
var setHeader = function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa($rootScope.login.Gebruikersnaam + ":" + $rootScope.login.Wachtwoord));
}

$rootScope.getCollection = function () {
    return new(Backbone.Collection.extend({
            url : $rootScope.login.Serverlocatie + '/Table?Active=true&SL=ID'
        }));
}

$rootScope.getCollection().fetch({
    beforeSend : setHeader
}).then(function (a) {
    console.log(a);
});
```

Normally, it should do a GET operation with the specified request header. However, i take the following as response:

```
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:400 Not a REST method:
```

So, OPTIONS method is not allowed and if i do just a GET operation (using ajax), it is working well.

The question is: how can i make GET call instead of OPTIONS in this case?

Comment: are you using backbone and angular together?

Comment: yes i use them both.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `type` field into `fetch` attributes:

```
$rootScope.getCollection().fetch({
    beforeSend : setHeader,
    type: 'GET'
}).then(function (a) {
    console.log(a);
});
```

Comment: are you sure about it? I tried it but still it is considered as a OPTION operation